# How to send bulk notifications for ios devices ? im trying but is sending for only one user always

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send bulk notifications for iOS devices but always it is going to one device only.

here is my syntax:

```
curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key= Dynamic generatedkey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"to": "deviceId1"
   "content_available" : true,
    "priority" : "high",
     "notification": {
    "sound" : "default",
    "title" : "TESt",
     "body"  : "1234",
      "type": "HELLO1",
      "notificationId": "100",
      "ticker": "test"

 }

"to": "deviceId2" : true,
    "priority" : "high",
     "notification": {
    "sound" : "default",
    "title" : "TESR  Offers2",
     "body"  : "trial2",
      "type": "4567",
      "notificationId": "100",
      "ticker": "Test2"

 }
}' https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send
```

Comment: this is tagged with "Google cloud messaging", but you're saying this is an IOS problem... which is it? GCM or APNS?

Comment: Yes am sending notifications through GCM .. for one deviceId it is working properly but for multiple users it is giving "INVALID_REGISTRATION" error

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is definitely completely invalid (missing enclosing `[]` to make it an array, missing opening `{` for the second object, missing separating `,`...). Use your preferred language's JSON encoding functions to create the JSON.

Comment: curl -X POST -H "Authorization: key= AppKey" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"to": "DeviceId"
   "content_available" : true,
    "priority" : "high",
     "notification": {
    "sound" : "default",
    "title" : "TES1",
     "body"  : "1234",
      "type": "NOTIF",
      "notificationId": "100",
      "ticker": "Monday1"

 }
}' https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send

Comment: the above code snippet is working my problem am not able to send notification for multiple users ..

Comment: Please go read the [GCM documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#send-downstream) for details on how to add more recipients to your message.